# Covariant derivative in a basis

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Reading through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0301509), I saw that the energy momentum conservation:

$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$$

can be evaluated as:

$$\partial_t(\sqrt{-g}T^{t}_\nu)=-\partial_i(\sqrt{-g}T^{i}_\nu)+\sqrt{-g}T^{\kappa}_\lambda\Gamma_{\nu\kappa}^{\lambda}$$

Can someone explain how this is done?

I guess this might be a simple question, but not having the experience, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the Levi-Civita connection (torsion-free and metric compatible) of a rank 2 covariant tensor in a coordinate patch $(t,x^i)$ has the following evaluation (please comment further if you want a derivation of this law),

$ \nabla_{\alpha}T^{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\alpha}T^{\mu\nu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}T^{\beta\nu}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\alpha\beta}T^{\mu\beta}$

Contracting on $\alpha$ and $\mu$ gives,

$ \nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\beta\nu}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\mu\beta}=0$

by conservation. Multiplying by $\sqrt{-g}$ gives,

$\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}T^{\mu\nu})-T^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g})+\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\beta\nu}+\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\mu\beta}=0$

Note that,

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}=gg^{\alpha\beta}\implies \partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g})=\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta}$

Further,

$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\alpha}g_{\beta\nu}+\partial_{\beta}g_{\alpha\nu}-\partial_{\nu}g_{\alpha\beta})\implies \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\beta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\beta\nu}+\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu\nu}-\partial_{\nu}g_{\mu\beta})=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu\nu})$

by the symmetry of the inverse metric. So,

$\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g})=\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha\mu}$

from the chain rule. Finally,

$\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}T^{\mu\nu})-\sqrt{-g}T^{\mu\nu}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha\mu}+\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\beta\nu}+\sqrt{-g}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\beta}T^{\mu\beta}=0$

Hence the result. Note I've been liberal with my use of relabelling dummy indices. Hopefully, this doesn't cause problems.

Edit: elaboration on derivative of the determinant.

We can write the determinant as,

$g=\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1}g_{\mu\nu}C^{\mu\nu}$

where $(C^{\mu\nu})$ is the cofactor matrix. Hence,

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}=C^{\mu\nu}$

Next recall that for an invertible matrix $A$, we have $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}C^T$, so $C^T=(\det A)A^{-1}$. The inverse metric is symmetric so we have,

$C^{\mu\nu}=g g^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your service. Could you elaborate more on $\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}=gg^{\alpha\beta}\implies \partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g})=\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta}$ On the first derivative and how it implies the latter

Comment: @MaxtronMoon please see the edits above. Hopefully, this helps.